# Give SVG and DIV the same background color with css

Tags: html, css, svg

I really did not understand much about masking/clipping. I´m trying something new with svg as a arrow for a chat bubble. Here is my pen:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/muuvmuuv/pen/pjRaVW)

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, div, b {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
 font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
 font: {
  size: 1.6rem;
  family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 }
 background-color: #132333;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.chat-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 60px 40px;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;

  &:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  .box {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 70%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;

    .user {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      float: inherit;
      vertical-align: top;

      img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }
    }

    .bubble {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
   float: inherit;
      max-width: 600px;
      min-height: 100%;
      padding: 5px 25px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 40px;
      
      p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    direction: ltr;
      }

      &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        float: inherit;
        top: 18px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 25px;
        -webkit-clip-path: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg);
        -webkit-mask: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg);
        clip-path: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg#svgClip);
        z-index: 0;
      }
    }

    .info {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }

    &.left {
      float:left;

      .user img {
        margin-right: 18px;
      }
      .bubble {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #4589D0 0%, #1B6FAB 100%);

        p { color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.9); }
        &::before {
          left: -12px;
          background: #4589D0;
        }
      }
      .info {
    left: 65px;
      }
    }
    &.right {
      float:right;

      .user img {
        margin-left: 18px;
      }
      .bubble {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

        p { color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5); }
        &::before {
          right: -12px;
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
          -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
          -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
          -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
          transform: scaleX(-1);
          -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
          filter: fliph; /*IE*/
        }
      }
      .info {
    right: 65px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
<div class="msg">
 <div class="box left">
  <div class="user">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/515651751291006977/MrdYuJ3C_400x400.png" alt="username">
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
   <p>Hey digger, wie gehts dir. Hast du schon gehört das cih jetzt ein neues chatt-app erstelle für den Brwoser? Nein okey dann schau mal hier</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
   <b class="pe-clock"></b> <b>Sent</b> 8:50 AM, <b>From</b> Cologne
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="msg">
 <div class="box right">
  <div class="user">
   <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/515651751291006977/MrdYuJ3C_400x400.png" alt="username">
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
   <p>Hey digger, wie gehts dir.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
   <b class="pe-clock"></b> <b>Sent</b> 8:50 AM, <b>From</b> Cologne
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div><!-- .chat-container -->
```

So my question is: how can I give the svg before element and the div itself the same background color. Right now both are overlapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix would be, if you used a solid color instead of a transparent one.

replace

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
```

with

```
background: #2A3847;
```

With that the overlap wont be visible.

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep transparency, you can make the bubble shape separate from the text, stretch it over your original bubble and make it solid color with opacity:

```html
<div class="bubble">
    <p>Hey digger, wie gehts dir.</p>
    <div class="bubble-shape"></div>
</div>
```

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: inherit;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* p css */
    .bubble-shape {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 40px;
        z-index: -1;
        &::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            float: inherit;
            top: 18px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 25px;
            -webkit-clip-path: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg);
            -webkit-mask: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg);
            clip-path: url(http://imgh.us/bubble.svg#svgClip);
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    p { /* css */ }
}
&.left {
    /* css */
    .bubble {
        .bubble-shape {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #4589D0 0%, #1B6FAB 100%);
            /* p css */
            &::before {
                left: -12px;
                background: #4589D0;
            }
        }
    }
    /* css */
}
&.right {
    /* css */
    .bubble {
        .bubble-shape {
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* solid color */
            opacity: 0.1; /* add opacity */
            /* p css */
            &::before {             
                right: -12px;
                background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* solid color */
                -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
                transform: scaleX(-1);
                -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
                filter: fliph; /*IE*/
            }
        }
    }
    /* css */
}
```

[full codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNgrPE)

Comment: Thank you ! That was it ... great idea with another layer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig very far into the issues you might have with svgs, but it looks like your problem is just using a background color with opacity.

I just switched to using full opacity color on the bubble and the arrow and it fixed it.

```
background: rgba(41, 57, 71, 1);
```

[image: screenshot of working solution]